# How to loop the CollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, slide

I have a set of collectionviewcell in  UICollectionView and i am using function NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval to command each cell to show up and move to the left in every 4 second. Currently,  they are not in loop and it ends up blank on the screen once the last cell shows up. How can I create the loop for these cells and make them to move continuously? Please advise.

```
func timeSlide() {

    var timeslide = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector: Selector("onTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func onTime(){

    collection.contentOffset = CGPointMake(collection.contentOffset.x+375, 0)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know how many items are there in the collection view, and when it gets to the end you need to set the `contentOffset` back to the beginning.